# How to achieve this kind of animation for my site..?

Tags: javascript, ajax

If you see [this](http://www.ftse.com) link you will find one map on the map.. onmouseover they were displaying some table data? can an one tell me how they did I hope they used Flash ajax, javascript,or (java with flex) can anyone tel me?

Comment: That's flash. You can tell by right-clicking on it. It is loading data from FTSEIndexes.xml every 15 seconds

Comment: Hmmm..thanks I thought soo.. 
can we achieve same kind of things using javascript or any other scripting?

My work is to get the indexes from databse to show on mouseover thing/
thanks

Comment: Bec for my apaplication I have Flash world map on my page.. I would like to achieve same kind of animiation for my page.. 
Can you give me sujjestion how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking through [some of these examples](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&q=dhtml+tooltips&btnG=Search)... a lot people have solved this problem so you don't have to.